# expl3 renew msg?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, expl3

Using lualatex, Linux, TeXlive 2023.

When `fontspec` cannot find a requested font, it issues a message,
defined as follows (using expl3):

```
\__fontspec_msg_new:nnn {font-not-found}
 {
  The font "#1" cannot be found.
 }
 {
  A font might not be found for many reasons.\\
  Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.\\\\
  When in doubt, ask someone for help!
 }
```

In my case, with a custom document class, there is exactly one reason why
a font is not found, and specific instructions to fix the problem. This is because the user choice of fonts is limited. So I want to re-define the above message. Immediately after `fontspec` loads,
but before it looks for any fonts, I want something like this:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\__fontspec_msg_new:nnn {font-not-found}
 {
  The font "#1" cannot be found.
 }
 {
  You need to install package "this-font-package".\\
  If your system does not allow you to install packages,\\
  then download the font package zip archive, unzip it,\\
  and place the *.otf files in the same directory as the main document.
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

I did not expect that to work (it did not work), but I tried hacking it
with `\__fontspec_msg_renew` which also does not work (apparently no such
thing as msg_renew).

No doubt expl3 can handle this. O gurus, how?

Comment: Messages can be `set` but you are not issuing a `fontspec` error, rather a class one that should do it's own testing

Comment: @rallg I recommend re-asking the question you asked me below but addressing it to Joseph Wright ;).

Comment: @JosephWright I have no problem issuing class errors. But fontspec gets there first, issuing its own error message, before my class can issue its message. Is it sufficient to modify `{fontspec}` to `{mydocclass}` in the `\msg_set` code, or do I need to do more? For example, I could try re-defining `\GenericError` or `\PackageError`, which does work for another package that does not use expl3 syntax.

Comment: After playing with it... It seems that the simplest solution is to write `This message is issued by myownclass, rather than fontspec:` (with tildes instead of spaces) at the top of the fontspec message.

Comment: @rallg I see the point, but conceptually this is not a `fontsepc` error - a class that needs other stuff installed should check itself (and for fonts, I'd say one cannot rely on a non-TeX font, you always need a fallback).

Comment: (Of course, if you are in an environment where a commercial font is in use, then the entire setup should be predicable ...)

Comment: @JosephWright Indeed. A fallback is also there (and custom error msg if missing). No commercial font. In most cases, my class pre-screens settings, and issues errors before some other package gets to it. But in this case, I am trying to avoid having `fontspec` scan in some locations (where non-licensed fonts might exist). So the actual message is more complex than shown in the MWE. But that is outside the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can  use `\msg_set:nnnn` to set a new text for the message, but as mentioned in the comments, you should probably not do this, but instead issue an error from your own class or package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_set:nnnn {fontspec} {font-not-found}
 {
  The~font~"#1"~cannot~be~found.
 }
 {
You~need~to~install~package~"this-font-package".\\
If~your~system~does~not~allow~you~to~install~packages,\\
then~download~the~font~package~zip~archive,~unzip~it,\\
and~place~the~*.otf~files~in~the~same~directory~as~the~main~document.
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\setmainfont{foo.otf}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

If you want the message to change using `\AtBeginDocument` you need to define a `\NewDocumentCommand` to do it:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fixerror}{}{
\msg_set:nnnn {fontspec} {font-not-found}
 {
  The~font~"##1"~cannot~be~found.
 }
 {
You~need~to~install~package~"this-font-package".\\
If~your~system~does~not~allow~you~to~install~packages,\\
then~download~the~font~package~zip~archive,~unzip~it,\\
and~place~the~*.otf~files~in~the~same~directory~as~the~main~document.
 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\AtBeginDocument{\fixerror}
```

Comment: Thanks! That does what it needs to do. And, now I can apply the method to some other package error messages, here and there.

Comment: Follow-up: I would like the message to change `\AtBeginDocument`. After changing the message, then I would attempt to load the font. But when I do that, I get the error that `\msg` is undefined. Is there something about `\msg_set' that changes, when it is wrapped `\AtBeginDocument`? If this is not obvious, I could provide a longer MWE.

Comment: @rallg I've shown how to do that.

Comment: Thanks again! Works. I would never have figured that out. Timing is everything...

Comment: @rallg You really shouldn't be claiming these messages originate from other packages.

Comment: @cfr Fair enough. I worried about that. Is it sufficient to change `{fontspec}` to `{mydocclass}` in the expl3 code, or is there another way? I suppose I could also redefine what fontspec does in terms of `\GenericError` and `\GenericWarning`. I have already doe that for another package that did not use expl3 syntax.